# multiChart Data read as undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to create an ndv3 multiChart, and the data seems to be passing from the Model to the View correctly when examining the HTML source code, but the graph shows neither the x-axis nor the data, which it says are undefined.  When using sample data like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n2hfN/28/), the graph shows, and I've used this same method when drawing simpler charts like a line or mutliBar.  Am I missing some formatting issue on multiChart data?  Many thanks in advance!

Here's the Javascript:

```
<script src="/Content/lib/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/lib/novus-nvd3/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 120, left: 70 };
    var svg = "#nvd3_multiChart svg";

    nv.addGraph(function () {
        var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
            .options({ reduceXTicks: false })
            .margin(margin)
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
        ;

        chart.xAxis
            .tickFormat(function (d) {
                return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
            });

        var nSold = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.nSoldObject))');
        var hSold = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.hSoldObject))');
        var sSold = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.sSoldObject))');
        var wSold = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.wSoldObject))');
        var bought = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.boughtObject))');

        var seriesData = [{ "key": "NSold", "type": "bar", "yAxis": 1, "values": nSold }, { "key": "HSold", "type": "bar", "yAxis": 1, "values": hSold }, { "key": "SSold", "type": "bar", "yAxis": 1, "values": sSold }, { "key": "WSold", "type": "bar", "yAxis": 1, "values": wSold }, { "key": "Bought", "type": "line", "yAxis": 2, "values": bought }];

        // Get max values for each axis
        var minY1 = 0;
        var minY2 = 0;
        var maxY1 = 0;
        var maxY2 = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
            var _axis = seriesData[i].yAxis;
            var _values = seriesData[i].values;

            // Walk values and set largest to variables
            for (var j = 0; j < _values.length; j++) {
                // For maxY1
                if (_axis == 1) {
                    if (_values[j].y > maxY1) {
                        maxY1 = _values[j].y;
                    }
                }
                // For maxY2
                if (_axis == 2) {
                    if (_values[j].y > maxY2) {
                        maxY2 = _values[j].y;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Set min, max values of axis
        chart.yDomain1([minY1, maxY1]);
        chart.yDomain2([minY2, maxY2]);

        // Set chart
        d3.select(svg)
            .datum(seriesData)
            .call(chart)
        ;

        // Auto resize chart on window resize
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
</script>
```

Here's an example of what the Chrome Console shows for data values, which appear correct:

```
var nSold = JSON.parse('[[1448928000000,18],[1451606400000,18],[1454284800000,18],[1456790400000,18]]');
```

And the error occurs at the end on the "//Set chart" section in d3.min.js:

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute transform="translate(undefined,0)"

Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,0)"
```

Comment: Have you got soolution for this?

Comment: No, I couldn't figure out what was wrong.  I ended up separating the one complex multi graph into several bar graphs with multiple bars.  If you find the solution, please post it here!

Comment: I'm using ES6, so inorder to get access to d3 object, I was importing d3 which is a node_module caused this error. I'm not sure in your case.